# Get 401 "Signature mismatch. Authorization signature or client credential is wrong." (JS)

Tags: here-api

When I call API to get token, this message shows up and I don't know why and how to fix it [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3LBI.png)

And this is my Authorization: `OAuth oauth_consumer_key="V3R6bm******DznqE-ellA", oauth_nonce="bbo8dYK6anE6JZsEIhj2RmKuEwV0****", oauth_signature="UQH1OnFWEscFbyZIx4DRn9qSOW+nvIlzCEgXrjm***=", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256", oauth_timestamp="1654152360", oauth_version="1.0"`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please refer to the below documentation and follow the instructions on using tokens on the HERE platform. https://developer.here.com/documentation/identity-access-management/dev_guide/topics/dev-token.html

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the below Steps to use OAuth 2.0 tokens and follow the instructions:

Step 1: Register your application

1. If you don't already have a HERE account, see Get a HERE account.
2. Sign in to developer.here.com.
3. Click your name, select Projects, and then your project from the list. Your project details and available application credentials are then displayed.
4. Select REST or HERE SDKs and click Generate App. When your application is created, its App ID is displayed.
5. Click Create Credentials to generate a maximum of two access keys for your application. The access key is created and displayed in a pop-up window. Download and securely store the access key secret. Also download the credentials.properties file as instructed.

Step 2: Get a token
For instructions on getting a token, see Code an OAuth 2.0 token request.

Step 3: Use the token
You have now successfully obtained an access bearer token to use in making REST requests to HERE APIs.

Include the token in the HTTP Authorization header of your REST requests as a bearer token:

```
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

Sample REST Request

```
GET /maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/normal.day/13/4400/2686/256/png8
Host: 1.base.maps.ls.hereapi.com
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGceOyJSAMPLEiIsImN0eSISAMPLEt7VTFIllwIM0cKNCjN2WCCTqlwEEmk-t3gx1BpqUFoeBSAMPLEvhj8nl-RBGcyoljY...
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Note: If you are upgrading to API key and currently have old app code credentials, you can remove them by clicking Remove APP CODE credentials and use your new API key credentials in their place.

For more details refer to the following documentation link: https://developer.here.com/documentation/identity-access-management/dev_guide/topics/dev-token.html